# How do I shift the heaviside function and solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, function-construction

I would like to solve $$y''+y'-2y=6H(t-3)\qquad y(0)=0  \qquad y'(0)=0$$ using mathematica. [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) it says how to write down the standard Heaviside. How do I shift it?

And how do I solve the pdf?

I tried

```
ode = DSolve[{y''[t]+y'[t]-2*y[t] == 6*HeavisideTheta[t],y[0]==0, y'[0]==0},y[t],t]
```

But I don't know what else to do

Comment: Don't you want `HeavisideTheta[t - 3]`?

Comment: yeah I didn't know how to shift it!

Comment: Basically it works just like formulas, except you have to use `[ ]` with functions instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you not finish your DSolve?

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[t] + y'[t] - 2*y[t] == 6*HeavisideTheta[t - 3], 
     y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t] // Simplify // First
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]